# Error with a simple Spinner on Android

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm learning about Spinners in Android, and I've tested the code that appears in this link of Android Developers:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

But it doesn't work, these are the files:

MainActivity.java

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
             R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
...
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.spinners.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Spinners</string>    
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
```

When I try the app show some errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.spinners, PID: 1381
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spinners/com.example.spinners.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.spinners.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    ... 11 more
```

Line 28 is:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Could you explain me why it's now working? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer @maraci, this is the solution:

The code that populates the spinner must be placed inside fragment's class, in onCreateView method , so MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);               

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }                
    }        

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);            
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);            
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);         
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently loading the layout activity_main.xml:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

but your spinner is defined in the layout called fragment_main.xml

change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

EDIT:
As per the comments, it seems that the issue was that you were not loading your fragment before trying to access elements in its xml layout from your activity.

Comment: Thanks for that, but there are other methods in MainActivity.java that manages the layouts "activity_main" and "fragment_main", if I put in comments the code that populates the Spinner it works, but with an empty Spinner, so, the error is filling the Spinner.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm just unsure of what your current Activity/Fragment setup currently is. 
I believe the issue, according to the information in your question, is that the findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner) returns null. To me, this seems like it's because the view containing the spinner in xml is never loaded, and your activity doesn't know anything about it.
What do you mean "if I put in comments the code that populates the spinner works"? Commenting out code?

Comment: Also, you might be loading your fragment code at a later time in the lifecycle of your activity. If that's the case, then it makes sense that you're getting a null return when trying to find the spinner since the fragment has not yet been loaded. Make sure you load the fragment first THEN use the findViewById on your spinner.

Comment: Hello, my internet connection was down... You were right, the spinner was null because I'm trying to using it before creating it. I'll post where I placed that code.

Comment: No worries. Glad you were able to find the issue!